# Plugins to open deployed contract in IDE?

Tags: contract-development, explorers, ide, visual-studio-code

I can view contract code from the browser eg https://etherscan.io/address/0x8509d347caa93e7db87e0287ee51867bfcb7b9d2#code or on avax eg https://cchain.explorer.avax.network/address/0xd1c3f94DE7e5B45fa4eDBBA472491a9f4B166FC4/contracts .

This is super cool but kind of a pain for actually trying to understand the code. Is there a VSCode plugin that takes a contract address and downloads copies of the contract code to files in the IDE where you can analyze or fork them more easily? Browser-based is also ok if it's an actual IDE with code analysis and assisted editing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the short answer is no, but you can use the [Solidity Visual Developer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintinweb.solidity-visual-auditor) extension in VS Code, or the [solidity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity) extension, or you can copy and paste the contracts onto an online IDE called [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2.js).